# Why does maven pom.xml file show error once i add apache poi dependency to it?

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot application using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)).
I just noticed that once add Apache poi dependency to my spring application maven pom.xml file,

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

The pom.xml shows an error icon which prevents the application from running.
When i remove this dependency, everything works fine.

I just can not tell what is causing this error or what i am doing wrong.
Your help will be so much appreciated.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score -1):

Try updating the maven project after adding your dependency to the project
Right click on the project --> Maven --> Update project.

or run the maven goal :

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This should update the IDE.

Or if you are having issues while running the project it might be because
`poi` is a transitive dependency for `poi-ooxml` .So, that must be causing the issue because of incompatible versions. So if you want to explicitly provide the version of `poi`, try excluding it from the `poi-ooxml` , and then specify it in the pom as you did.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: That won't help or change a thing. Declaring a transative dependency as a top-level dependency doesn't cause errors. It might only cause errors at runtime when they are incompatible.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you,have updated the answer according to your input and my understanding of the issue.Was interpreting the question differently.

Comment: He gets an exception in the `pom.xml` not at runtime.